# How to Read a file with Ç as Delimiter in Pyspark (SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file)

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark

Experts, I am trying to Read a file delimited with ccedilla (Ç) in Pyspark, typed as ALT+0199 and it works well when i do it in Pyspark Shell (Spark 1.6, Python 2.7)

```
$ hdfs dfs -cat /user/user1/test.dat
AÇBÇC

>>> sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header","false").option("inferSchema","false").option("delimiter",'Ç').load("/user/user1/test.dat").show()
+---+---+---+
|_c0|_c1|_c2|
+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|
+---+---+---+
```

However, when i try to do the same in my Pyspark program (.py script), i get below error-

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file createDFs.py on line 53, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

I've tried proving these options in the script but wasn't able to get rid of this error.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Also, tried to give encoding in option-

```
df=sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header","true").option("inferSchema","false").option("delimiter",'Ç').option("encoding","utf-8").load("/user/user1/test.dat")
```

Comment: Add `.option("encoding", "...")` before the `.load()`. Pick the encoding the text file has. (a good text editor will give you a hint, the `file` command [can also be used](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11602/2579))

Comment: Your `# coding: utf-8` comment was not picked up by Python, otherwise you would get a different error (`SyntaxError: encoding problem: utf-8`). Did you put it in the first or second line of the script as PEP instructs?

Comment: thank you, it resolved my problem!